# Which sci-fi story had a space-traveling family stranded on a planet and the sons chased by an animal with a triangular-shaped body?

Tags: story-identification

Back in the '60s I started reading a sci-fi book about a travelling space family who became stranded on an unfamiliar world. The boys ventured out and were chased by an animal with a triangular-shaped body. One of the boys fell into a quicksand-type mess and was pulled out by his brother with a vine, which caused large red welts on his body. I had to turn the book in  before I finished reading it and have been unable to recall the title or author, and, strange as it sounds because I am in my sixties now, would like to finish the children's sci-fi book I started fifty years ago.

Comment: That isn't Space Family Robinson, is it?

Comment: Do you remember any more about the triangular-shaped animals?  I mean were they robots, animals with sharp claws, spider-like scary animals, or?? It might help.